# Truncate long month names in time axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to work out how to change the formatting for months when drawing an axis with a scaleTime data range.

I've been able to manage the layout as expected, but i'd like the full month names to be truncated. See the example below - I'd like "February" to be "Feb".
The other dates are fine.

[image]

The summary of my axis code is:

```
  const x = scaleTime()
    .domain(dateExtent)
    .rangeRound([marginSize.left, width - marginSize.right]);

  const xAxis = axisBottom(x)
    .ticks(timeDay.every(2))
    .tickSizeOuter(0);
```

Is there a means of providing the formatting for those date values?

Comment: It's this specific feature I'm trying to control: https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#time_tickFormat

The month boundary is set to `%B` but it'd like it to be `%b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and fastest alternative is just using `tickFormat` with the specifier you want, so all ticks will have the same structure.

However, assuming you want to change only the boundary ticks (for a format that doesn't match the adjacent ones, as you described), you can get the ticks after the axis generator created them and check their value.

For instance, an axis with *February*, like yours:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([20, 580])
  .domain([new Date("January 20, 2020"), new Date("February 10, 2020")]);
const axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,50)"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

We get the ticks and check if the text matches the desired specifier, otherwise we change it:

```
d3.selectAll(".tick text").each(function(d) {
  if (this.textContent !== d3.timeFormat("%a %d")(d)) this.textContent = d3.timeFormat("%b")(d);
});
```

Here is the result:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([20, 580])
  .domain([new Date("January 20, 2020"), new Date("February 10, 2020")]);
const axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,50)"));

d3.selectAll(".tick text").each(function(d) {
  if (this.textContent !== d3.timeFormat("%a %d")(d)) this.textContent = d3.timeFormat("%b")(d);
});

svg.append("ellipse")
  .attr("cx", 342)
  .attr("cy", 63)
  .attr("rx", 20)
  .attr("ry", 8)
```

```css
ellipse {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```